# Center character inside a span with same width and height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center characters inside a  `span`.

**CSS**

```
span{border-radius:10px; width:20px; height:20px; color:#fff; background:#cc0000; text-align:center; line-height:20px; display:block;}
```

**HTML**

```
<span>+</span><br>
<span>-</span>
```

As you can see, the characters are a little bit off on the bottom right. How to perfectly center align that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/5U7qj/

Comment: Don't see a problem on Chrome, what are you expecting to see?

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0942owzk8c I'm on Chrome too on Win 8 and look at the image, the characters are a bit too much on the bottom right side.

Comment: When “-” is clearly meant to stand for a minus sign, you should use the real MINUS SIGN “−” instead (using perhaps `&minus;` in HTML). It has properties different from those of “-” HYPHEN-MINUS, so you should get the character right before fine-tuning the rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using an even value for your height and width. Since the characters are only 1 pixel in thickness it will look off until you either change them to a 2 pixel thickness or change the `width`, `height` and `line-height` to be an odd value. Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5U7qj/10/)

Comment: looks like it's true for the `+` but the `-` is still not centered correctly.

Comment: Weird, it's centered in Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: Noice! The famous 1px bug. Same thing with 33% width thing that browser don't take decimals to convert it to 33.3333333%. Thanks m8

Comment: @MatthewR. I've tried both the latest versions of Opera and Chrome (34), they are both the same, snapshot here http://i.imgur.com/FCTsJYr.png

Comment: Ah, that might be an issue with your font's aliasing. Try line height as 18px and see if that fixes that.

Comment: @MatthewR. I had to try setting `line-height:16px` to make the `-` vertically centered (in fact it's not really horizontally centered, being offset a little about 1px maybe), however the `+` is moved upwards and not vertically centered anymore. So we have to use 2 separate rules for the `span`s. Anyway, I would use `:before` and `:after` to render the `+` and `-` to avoid the issue of this kind.